# Sugestões para melhoria de código

Tags: c++, jogos

Boa noite, criei um Joga da Forca em C++ como exercício e gostaria de receber sugestões para melhoria de código. Agradeço desde já quem poder responder.

Segue o código:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string palavfr_secreta;
std::string dica;
std::string esconde;

short chances;
short acertos;
short erros;

void jogo(){

    std::string letra_digitada;
    std::string letra_secreta;
    std::string letra_esconde;

    short contador=0;

    std::cout << "================== " << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Dica-------------> " << dica << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Palavra secreta--> " << esconde << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Chances----------> " << chances << std::endl;
    std::cout << "================== " << std::endl << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Digite uma letra-> ";
    std::cin >> letra_digitada;

    std::cin.ignore();

    if(letra_digitada.size()>1){

        system("cls");

        std::cout << "DIGITE SOMENTE UMA LETRA!" << std::endl;

        jogo();

    }else{

        for(unsigned i=0; i<palavfr_secreta.size(); i++){

            letra_secreta=palavfr_secreta.at(i);
            letra_esconde=esconde.at(i);

            if(letra_digitada.compare(letra_esconde)==0){

                system("cls");

                std::cout << "Você não pode digitar a mesma letra mais de uma vez" << std::endl;

                chances--;

                break;

            }else if(letra_digitada.compare(letra_secreta)==0){

                system("cls");

                esconde.at(i)=letra_digitada.at(0);

                contador++;
                acertos++;

            }else if(i==palavfr_secreta.size()-1 && contador==0){

                system("cls");

                std::cout << "Letra não correspondente" << std::endl;

                chances--;
                erros++;
            }
        }
    }

    if(chances==0){

        system("cls");

        std::cout << "======================================================================" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Você perdeu! A frase ou palavra secreta era " << "'" << palavfr_secreta << "'" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Total de acertos -> " << acertos << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Total de erros -> " << erros << std::endl;
        std::cout << "======================================================================" << std::endl;

    }else if(esconde.compare(palavfr_secreta)==0){

        system("cls");

        std::cout << "=======================================================================" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Você acertou! A frase ou palavra secreta era " << "'" << palavfr_secreta << "'" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Total de acertos -> " << acertos << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Total de erros -> " << erros << std::endl;
        std::cout << "=======================================================================" << std::endl;

    }else{

        jogo();
    }
}

int main(){

    std::cout << "===============Jogo da Forca===============" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Digite uma palavra ou frase secreta-> ";
    getline(std::cin, palavfr_secreta);

    system("cls");

    std::cout << "Escreva uma dica-> ";
    getline(std::cin, dica);

    system("cls");

    std::cout << "Defina o número de Chances-> ";
    std::cin >> chances;

    for(unsigned i=0; i<palavfr_secreta.size(); i++){

        if(palavfr_secreta.at(i)==' '){
            esconde+=" ";
        }else{
            esconde+="-";
        }
    }

    system("cls");

    jogo();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Não é bem esse o intuito dessa comunidade e a sua pergunta é bem ampla, o que exatamente procura melhorar?

Comment: @Leandro Angelo Gostaria de saber se no meu código tem erros relacionados a má pratica de programação ou outra coisa que possa interferi na funcionalidade do código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O nosso formato não é bem de revisão de código, isso aplica-se mais ao que existe na versão inglesa de [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), ainda assim, seguem algumas dicas minhas de melhorias que pode fazer:

- Evite fazer loops/laços/ciclos à custa de recursão. Algo que está a fazer aqui:

  ```
  void jogo(){
      if(chances==0){
          ...
      }else if(esconde.compare(palavfr_secreta)==0){
          ...
      }else{
          jogo();
      }
  ```

  Não só é bem menos eficiente, como pode mesmo rebentar o programa com o clássico *Stack Overflow Exception*. Isto porque está constantemente a abrir novas funções iguais no stack até potencialmente rebentar.

  A forma de solucionar este problema é transformando a recursão num laço com `while` ou `for` por exemplo.
- Quando acede a uma letra de uma `string` é mais idiomático o acesso pelo operador indexação, o `[]` ao invés de `palavfr_secreta.at(i)`
- Tente colocar as variáveis o mais perto possível da sua utilização:

  ```
  void jogo(){

      std::string letra_digitada;
      std::string letra_secreta;
      std::string letra_esconde; //<----------- declarada aqui

      short contador=0;

      std::cout << "================== " << std::endl;
      std::cout << "Dica-------------> " << dica << std::endl;
      std::cout << "Palavra secreta--> " << esconde << std::endl;
      std::cout << "Chances----------> " << chances << std::endl;
      std::cout << "================== " << std::endl << std::endl;
      std::cout << "Digite uma letra-> ";
      std::cin >> letra_digitada;

      std::cin.ignore();

      if(letra_digitada.size()>1){

          system("cls");

          std::cout << "DIGITE SOMENTE UMA LETRA!" << std::endl;

          jogo();

      }else{

          for(unsigned i=0; i<palavfr_secreta.size(); i++){

              letra_secreta=palavfr_secreta.at(i);
              letra_esconde=esconde.at(i); //<---------utilizada aqui
  ```

  Embora possa ser (potencialmente) mais eficiente em alguns casos acaba por prejudicar consideravelmente a leitura, pois fica difícil de saber onde a variável está a ser utilizada. E se for numa ótica de otimização, provavelmente será otimização prematura que até o próprio compilador a conseguirá fazer.
- Para saber se um determinado caratere existe numa `string` tem o método [`find` da `string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/) que lhe facilita o trabalho podendo converter o seu `for` e primeiro `if`:

  ```
  for(unsigned i=0; i<palavfr_secreta.size(); i++){
      letra_secreta=palavfr_secreta.at(i);
      letra_esconde=esconde.at(i);

      if(letra_digitada.compare(letra_esconde)==0){
          ....
  ```

  Em

  ```
  if (esconde.find(letra_digitada) != std::string::npos){
  ```

  Assumindo que `letra_digitada` é um `char`.
- Tente usar os tipos mais apropriados para os seus valores. Quando está a ler um `char` como no caso da `letra_digitada`, leia para uma variável do tipo `char`. Isto acaba por lhe facilitar de seguida as comparações.

  Podendo transformar isto:

  ```
  }else if(letra_digitada.compare(letra_secreta)==0){
  ```

  Nisto

  ```
  }else if(letra_digitada == palavra_secreta[i]){
  ```
- O bloco que tem para quando não encontra a letra digitada no `for`:

  ```
  for(unsigned i=0; i<palavfr_secreta.size(); i++){
      ...
      }else if(i==palavfr_secreta.size()-1 && contador==0){
          system("cls");
          std::cout << "Letra não correspondente" << std::endl;
          chances--;
          erros++;
      }
  }
  ```

  Devia na verdade estar fora do `for`. Faria isso colocando dentro do `for` apenas o `if` de quando a letra existe e alterando o valor de uma *flag*. Depois a seguir ao `for` testa a *flag* para saber acertou em alguma letra.

Aplicando todas essas melhorias que sugeri o código ficaria assim:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string palavra_secreta,dica,esconde;    
short chances,acertos,erros;

void jogo(){
    //nova condição de fim do jogo
    while (acertos < palavra_secreta.size() && chances > 0){ 
        system("cls"); //apenas limpa aqui e não dentro do for como tinha
        std::cout << "================== " << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Dica-------------> " << dica << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Palavra secreta--> " << esconde << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Chances----------> " << chances << std::endl;
        std::cout << "================== " << std::endl << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Digite uma letra-> ";

        char letra_digitada; //agora como char
        std::cin >> letra_digitada;

        if (esconde.find(letra_digitada) != std::string::npos){//testa se existe com find
            system("cls");
            std::cout << "Você não pode digitar a mesma letra mais de uma vez" << std::endl;
            chances--;
        }
        else {
            int novos_acertos = 0;

            for(unsigned int i=0; i < palavra_secreta.size(); i++){
                if(letra_digitada == palavra_secreta[i]){ //apenas atualiza as letras
                    esconde[i]=letra_digitada;
                    novos_acertos++;
                    acertos++;
                }
            }

            if (novos_acertos == 0){ //se não acertou nenhuma mostra mensagem
                system("cls");
                std::cout << "Letra não correspondente" << std::endl;
                chances--;
                erros++;
            }
        }

        if(chances == 0){
            system("cls");
            std::cout << "======================================================================" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Você perdeu! A frase ou palavra secreta era " << "'" << palavra_secreta << "'" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Total de acertos -> " << acertos << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Total de erros -> " << erros << std::endl;
            std::cout << "======================================================================" << std::endl;
        }else if(esconde.compare(palavra_secreta) == 0){
            system("cls");
            std::cout << "=======================================================================" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Você acertou! A frase ou palavra secreta era " << "'" << palavra_secreta << "'" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Total de acertos -> " << acertos << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Total de erros -> " << erros << std::endl;
            std::cout << "=======================================================================" << std::endl;
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    std::cout << "===============Jogo da Forca===============" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Digite uma palavra ou frase secreta-> ";
    getline(std::cin, palavra_secreta);

    system("cls");
    std::cout << "Escreva uma dica-> ";
    getline(std::cin, dica);

    system("cls");
    std::cout << "Defina o número de Chances-> ";
    std::cin >> chances;

    for(unsigned i=0; i<palavra_secreta.size(); i++){
        esconde += palavra_secreta[i]==' ' ? " ":"_"; //com ternário para ficar simples
    }

    jogo();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Percebi que para uma pessoa jogar outra tem que digitar a palavra e dar a dica, Então você poderia salvar varias palavras por categoria em um arquivo e pega-las aleatoriamente.
exemplo no seu menu teria algo como escolha um tema.
-animais
-frutas
-cores  etc...
ai o jogador escolheria animais e o seu programa sortearia um palavra do arquivo animais.
caso queira fazer olhe as funções:rand() e srand() para aleatoriedade.
e a biblioteca: fstream para abrir arquivos.

Comment: Boa ideia! Irei fazer isso